# Rails: Strong parameters, Does it have to be present all the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As the title says. I know that strong parameters is to prevent other unauthorized attributes to be included when updating or creating new objects. I've seen codes that doesn't have strong parameters. For example in Hartl's tutorial `relationships controller`:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

and others have it included such as creating new post or user etc. so my question is, when is the practice to use strong parameters?

Answer (score 2):

Its ideal to use strong parameters when mass assigning values. Like creating new post or user. It may allows attackers to set any database column’s value.

Check out Rails official [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/security.html#mass-assignment) for it.

Doing like these is fine, as long as you know and mentioning model attributes.

```
@user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
@user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
```

Comment: your link is rails 3.2 guides

Answer (score 1):

I would say - use strong params for any actions where you use mass-assignment. This means that, actions like `create` or `update` must employ strong params.

For example, instead of having:

```
@object.update_attributes(params[:object])
```

Just have a:

```
@object.update_attributes(object_params)
```

Which will whitelist params for you. Also, it allows you to pass-through different params for different actions, with methods like `object_update_params` and `object_create_params` which will whitelist params for update and params for create, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, not using strong parameters will raise `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` so it's not optional unless you manage to override this behavior.

In the above example he is just retrieving a record and then creating a relationship with that id in the model.

```
def follow!(other_user)
  relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
end
```